# How to change a text variable to a number variable. Tkinter, Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I need help with changing "textvariable" to a int var. Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

strfname = IntVar()

strlname = IntVar()

labelf = Label(root, text = 'number').pack()
fname = Entry(root, justify='left', textvariable = strfname).pack() 

labell = Label(root, text = 'number 2').pack()
lname = Entry(root, justify='left', textvariable = strlname).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Since you used `IntVar`, it's already an integer. No conversion needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use .get

```
number_variable = strfname.get()
```

Comment: It's already an IntVar, that conversion is useless. Just use `get()`.